# Why am I getting an error!?(Null pointer Exception)

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am trying to create a program where a car dealership can pick what kind of customer and then enter in the info. It works fine up to where it prints the results. Then it gives me the error at the bottom. PLEASE HELP!! **I also need a way to add up the service objects and print them as well. Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 9999;
        Customer [] cust = new Customer[MAX];
        int choice = 0;
        int cnt;

        double total;

        for(cnt=0; cnt < MAX && choice == 1 || choice ==2 || choice == 0; cnt++){
            System.out.println("For a Service customer type 1, for a Purchaser type 2, to terminate the program press 9");
            choice = s.nextInt();
            switch (choice){
            case 1:
                cust [cnt] = new Service();
                break;
            case 2:
                cust [cnt] = new Purchaser();
                            break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < cnt; i++){
            cust[i].showData();
        }
        //for(int i=0; i < cnt; i++ ){
            //total = cust.
        //}
            s.close();

    }
}
interface Functions {
    public void getData();
    public void showData();
}
abstract class Customer implements Functions {
    protected String name;


}
class Purchaser extends Customer {
    protected double payment;

    public Purchaser(){
        getData();
    }

    public void getData() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the customer");
        name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter payment amount: ");
        payment = s.nextDouble();
    }
    public void showData() {    
        System.out.printf("Customer name: %s Payment amount is: %.2f\n",name,payment);

    }   
}
class Service extends Customer {
    protected String date;
    protected double amount;
    public Service () {
        getData();

    }

    public void getData() {     
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the customer");
        name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter date of Service: ");
        date = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the cost of Service: ");
        amount = s.nextDouble();
    }
    public void showData() {
        System.out.printf("Customer name: %s The date is: %s, the Amount owed is: %.2f\n",name, date, amount);
    }
}
```

---

```
Customer name: ;khhihl The date is: ljhljh, the Amount owed is: 555.00
Customer name: ljhjlhhj Payment amount is: 545454.00
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at prog24178.assignment.Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:30)
```

Comment: Please point us to the line referenced in your exception.  (30)

Comment: Now would be a pretty good (and easy) time to learn how to read a stack trace and debug manually.

Comment: did u try to debug it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: What is `cnt` when you get to the `for(int i=0;...` loop, and what do you think it should be?

Comment: it points to the for loop: cust[i].showData();

Comment: Your problem would be on line 30 of your file named "Assignment3.java".

Comment: cnt is the amount of entries entered.

Comment: @user278153 "cnt is the amount of entries entered".  Are you sure?  Try printing it.

Comment: Please use a Collection, say an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:  Sometimes a collection isn't necessarily needed, nor called for.  It could be the case that they don't know of the Java Collections Framework, or aren't allowed to use it.

Comment: every time a entry is entered cnt gets 1 added to it. How would this not print the amount of entries?

Comment: If you don't enter 1 or 2 then `cnt` gets incremented regardless of if an entity was placed into the array at that spot or not.  That's how the count could differ.

Comment: @Makoto True. But this seems like a good time for OP to learn about them (and an array of length `9999` offends me).

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user278153 arrays of Objects are by default filled with `null` values. Your first `for` loop initializes some - but not all - of the values. When your second `for` loop tries to call `showData()` on a null entry, you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Oh I see.  That makes sense. How could I fix that?

Comment: Fill the array with objects

Comment: I guess that's where I would need array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, inside the for loop with the call to `showData()`, that you add the following statement:

```
if(cust[i]!=null)
```

This will make sure that it never tries to read data from a space in the array where there is no customer. (Null pointer exceptions are caused by the program trying to access objects that have no data.)

You could get around most of the problem by using an `ArrayList<Customer>` instead of a `Customer[]`. This way, you can have any arbitrary number of customers, and if you get to the end of the customers that you have added, it doesn't try to look in places where there are no customers.